# Error parsing HTTP request header HTTP method names must be tokens with HTTPS spring Boot tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, https, postman

I'm trying to configure HTTPS in my spring boot application running on tomcat 9.0.39, but when I execute a POST in PostmanCanary, I'm receiving this error in my console.log:

```
2020-10-24 16:32:12.339  INFO 22073 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xf70x010x000x000xf30x030x030xb1Z0xba`0xd2q0xb10xa40xcdGk>.H0x190x0f0xe90xe20xeb0xbdJ80xc1l0y0xaa0x050x17'0x060xda]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:417) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

In PostmanCanary, besides this tomcat error, I receive this:

```
Error: write EPROTO 37322838446536:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:
```

My postmanCanary has the certificate imported in settings Client Certificates (i've imported my .p12 in PFX file option)

my server.xml has this commented:

```
<!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html 
<Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>-->
```

and this:

```
<Connector port="8081" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreType="PKCS12" keystoreFile="/home/...PATH_TO_P12.../base.p12" keystorePass="mypassword" truststoreType="PKCS12" truststoreFile="base.p12" truststorePass="mypassword" />
```

my application:

```
@ComponentScan("com.xxx.base")
@EntityScan("com.xxx.base.domain")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserRegistryApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }
    
     @Override
     protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(UserRegistryApplication.class);
     }
}
```

My security configuration (I don't want to authenticate, this is the first User Registry so there's no login yet, I just want to pass my POST Body with the user password in a secure way)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
              .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest()
              .authenticated()
              .and()
              .httpBasic();
        }

}
```

my application.properties(base.p12 is in resources with the properties):

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:base.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=mypassword
server.ssl.key-alias=base
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

my Controller:

```
    //POST /User {...} --> create not active User prototype
    @PostMapping("/createPrototype")
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUserPrototype(@RequestBody User requestUser) throws HttpClientErrorException, URISyntaxException, Exception{
        ...codes...

}
```

does any one know what i missing?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by my self.

first I generated another .p12 by using these commands:

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout base.pem -out base.pem -days 365 -nodes

openssl pkcs12 -export -out base.p12 -inkey base.pem -in base.pem

then, in my server.xml uncommented this:

```
<Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
```

and put his:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
keystoreFile="/home/...PATH_TO_P12.../base.p12"
keystorePass="password" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreType="PKCS12" />
```

my configuration is now like this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
          http.csrf().disable().httpBasic();
          
    }
```

In my postman I disabled SSL certificate verification on settings

and now works fine.